# How to get checked list and checked button bar value on button ng-click Ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

How to get selected list value and selected button bar value using ionic and Angular Js when i click on `fModalHide(1);`

```
$scope.fModalHide = function(index){

// I want to value of selected list and  selected button bar

}
```

```html
<p class="mypad"><i class="icon ion-ios-location-outline"></i> Location</p>
<ion-list class="mylist"><ion-radio ng-model="choice" value="pass" ng-value="'10'">Delhi</ion-radio>
<ion-radio ng-model="choice" value="pass" ng-value="'20'">Noida</ion-radio>
<ion-radio ng-model="choice" value="pass" ng-value="'30'">Gurgaon</ion-radio>
<ion-radio ng-model="choice" value="pass" ng-value="'40'">Ghaziabad</ion-radio>
<ion-radio ng-model="choice" value="pass" ng-value="'50'">Faridabad</ion-radio>
<ion-radio ng-model="choice" value="pass" ng-value="'60'">Greater Noida</ion-radio>
</ion-list>

<div class="button-bar">
<a class="button" ng-click="clicked(1)" ng-class="{'active': var == 1}">First</a>
<a class="button" ng-click="clicked(2)" ng-class="{'active': var == 2}">Second</a>
<a class="button" ng-click="clicked(3)" ng-class="{'active': var == 3}">Third</a>
</div>

<button class="button button-full button-small button-positive" ng-click="fModalHide(1)">Create</button>
```

Comment: it's not really clear what you are asking here.  have you checked the values of `$scope.var` and `$scope.choice`?

Answer (score 0):

You can create some $scope params for selected list and button:

```
$scope.selectedList = 20;
$scope.selectedButton = 1;
```

Then update these value when click button or radio. In function fModalHide you can get these value :

```
$scope.fModalHide = function(index){
 var selectedList =  $scope.selectedList;
 var selectedButton = $scope.selectedButton;
}
```